# Python3 restart a script from another script

Tags: python, subprocess, call

This is the situation:

I've 2 script in python running in 2 different shells in Linux:
1° - python3 server.py
2° - python3 roomcontrol.py

I need that the user can restart roomcontrol.py from server.py.
I tried with subprocess:

```
from subprocess import call

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/roomcontrol.py"
call(["python3",dir])
```

These instructions just start a new istance of "roomcontrol.py" in the shell of "server.py", I need to restart roomcontrol.py in his shell. Or close his shell and open a new one.

Edit:

I also tried:

```
import subprocess

dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/roomcontrol.py"
subprocess.Popen([dir], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

It doesn't work. 
It writes a lot of stuff in the same shell of server.py and my cursor become a cross and if I click somewhere it wrtes stuff like before. A little example of what it writes:

```
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9199.
import: unable to grab mouse `': Resource temporarily unavailable @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9199.
.
.
.
from: can't read /var/mail/xml.dom
/home/stark/Desktop/TrackingOk/Release/roomcontrol.py: 9: /home/stark/Desktop/Tr: not foundlease/roomcontrol.py: 
/home/stark/Desktop/TrackingOk/Release/roomcontrol.py: 10: /home/stark/Desktop/T: not foundelease/roomcontrol.py: try:
```

Comment: I haven't used subprocesses, but after a quick look in the documentation [Popen](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) looks promising.

Comment: did you add shebang to your script roomcontrol.py? (`#!/usr/bin/env python`)

Comment: @Olian04 I tried (I edited the post)

Comment: @slallum Yes I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new .sh file ("restart.sh" for example):

```
#!/bin/bash
kill $(pgrep -f 'python3 roomcontrol.py')
python3 roomcontrol.py &
```

Then just call

```
os.system('./restart.sh')
```

somewhere in your "server.py" script.

PS: You have to make the .sh file executable by running the following command:

```
chmod +x restart.sh
```

**Edit:** I'm not sure how you can start a process from a different shell, but you can start "roomcontrol.py" in another terminal window with the following (bash) command:

```
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'python3 roomcontrol.py'
```

But then you'd have to replace "restart.sh" by

```
#!/bin/bash
kill -9 $(pgrep -f 'sh -c python3 roomcontrol.py')
gnome-terminal -x sh -c 'python3 roomcontrol.py'
```

Comment: Hi Alek, thank you for the answer!
It works but I would need to run the script in the same shell of the one  we killed.

I don't know if I explained myself:
I want to close roomcontrol.py(maybe we can close the shell too) and open a new roomcontrol.py in the same shell(or in a new one if we close the old one).
Not the same shell of server.py...

Comment: I edited my answer but I'm not sure if this is what you need, hope it helps though

Comment: Hi, with "from a different shell" I meant "from a different  terminal window", my bad! :)
Thanks for the answer it seams to work!

Comment: Another thing: If I need to launch the restart.sh but it is in another dir? 
Example: server.py is in the "main" directory. 
restart.sh (and roomcontrol.py) are in main/child/.

Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Ok no problem , I solved it myself. Thank you again!